# set decimal places for type decimal in sails js

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm using MySQL with SailsJS (v1.0.0-45, beta). In my model, can I do this?

```
min_vol: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'decimal'
  length: '16,8'
}
```

In [the docs for v1](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/concepts/ORM/Attributes.md), it's specified that you need to use `type: 'number'`, but if I'm correct you can use any data type that your database type will support in `columnType`.

I can't find anything on specifying the length like you would do in your MySQL table, so my other question is if this is the right way of specifying the length as it's important that my data is stored in this way.

Note: I don't care about migrations to other database types (eg MongoDB) later, but would be interested in if/how this could be solved in a DB agnostic way.

Comment: what does 16,8 mean?

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to do it:

```
min_vol: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'decimal(16,8)'
}
```